# Failed to build Dockerfile.devel with error -Werror=maybe-uninitialized

Tags: c++, tensorflow-serving

I am building tensorflow-server from source code, [refer to doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/building_with_docker.md), but it was failed.

My environment:
Linux 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 
Docker 19.03.8

Build command:

```
docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel   -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel
```

Error output:

```
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/e53bbb0b0da4e26d24b415310219b953/external/upb/BUILD:57:1: C++ compilation of rule '@upb//:upb' failed (Exit 1)
external/upb/upb/table.c: In function 'upb_inttable_pop':
external/upb/upb/table.c:588:10: error: 'val.val' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   return val;
          ^~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Target //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 592.958s, Critical Path: 122.61s
INFO: 3550 processes: 3550 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this error when building latest version of Tensorflow Serving container. Looks like particular bazel version causes the error. I have found discussion under one of recent tensorflow serving updates - https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/162f72949c6ecbe9e610182c923dec0aa5924cf2. I tried workaround suggested there, changing Tensorflow Serving branch from *master* to *r2.1* by passing argument to docker build in such a way `--build-arg TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH=r2.1`, it helped.